# BlackBerry Equivalent to Android's Device Administration API?

Tags: android, camera, blackberry-10, device-admin

I have a goal to *disable the use of device camera* during a certain period of time.

My target platforms are **Android** and **BlackBerry**. For Android, it was very easy. Using [Device Administration API](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/admin/device-admin.html#overview), I can set a policy that will let my app disable/enable the camera on the fly:

```
DevicePolicyManager.setCameraDisabled(mDeviceAdminSample, true/false);
```

I am currently searching for a similar way on BlackBerry that will let me achieve the same outcome, disabling the camera.

Is there a way to do this on BlackBerry?